# How to run your feature file from multiple features file in a cucumber project

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, bdd

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xoxi.png)I already have a runner class with which I was running my feature file, that time I only had one feature file and that runner class is:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="Features",
                 tags = {"@E2E"},
                 glue={"stepdefinition"})
```

Now I added new feature file and my Feature folder looks like:

```
Booking.feature
smoketest.feature
```

How can I run my both feature files with same runner file or I have to create the new runnner file for 2 one.

**Note:** Latest feature file is `Booking.feature`.

It is giving me initialisation error when I changed the tag name

the error code:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.<init>(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader, io.cucumber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:53)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:35)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.loadBackends(Runtime.java:89)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:42)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:80)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.<init>(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader, io.cucumber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:45)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: No need to add a runner for each feature file. The runner config seems correct. Can u add the error to the question? Also remove the tag option and see if it works.

Comment: @Grasshopper Please see the error code , I tried removing tags but same error

Comment: Are all the version numbers of the relevant cucumber jars compatible? Are u using maven or jars directly?

Comment: I am using maven